# JQuery hover addclass not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use JQuery to change a picture inside of a nested li with an id of "logotest"

The classes I want applied are logotest1 and logotest2. Basically when the user hovers over the button, the picture is changed to a different one so the colors match. Here's a fiddle. Obviously the pictures aren't there, but maybe I am doing something wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/b9XHe/

I don't have the classes logotest1 and 2 in the fiddle - can it not dynamically changed the background image of the li?

Comment: You cannot have an UL -> A -> LI structure. You have to place the A inside LI.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It seems to work? The entire li is able to be clicked.

Comment: @Audi Btw you have to select "jQuery" in your demo (from the drop-down on the left). Otherwise your jQuery code won't work.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It is included somewhere else and I verified it works. I just cannot get it to properly change classes.

Comment: It seems to be working for me - http://i.imgur.com/6VdWv.jpg

Comment: @Audi It's not valid HTML. Don't fight the standard. You can set the A to be `display:block` so that it fills the entire LI....

Comment: @FloydPink there is an image (iconic.png) that is supposed to display when it is hovered upon. I cannot add that to a fiddle can I?

Comment: @FloydPink Basically my question is why when I hover over the LI, it doesn't switch to the proper class? I have a background-image I am setting when its not hovered over, and a different one when it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's working because there is a :hover in the css that kicks in, and you should read up on correct css syntax.

Here is an example of changing classes with backgrounds : http://jsfiddle.net/b9XHe/28/

Another way to do it in jQuery is directly thru the .css() function, something like this:

```
$("#logotest").css("background", "url(/images/newBG.jpg)");
```